# Python Memory Error with np.diag()

Tags: python, out-of-memory, opticalflow

I would like to implement the following equation (Exact solution of the Horn-Schunck Method):

[image: Exact solution of the Horn-Schunck Method]

My code:

```
def HS_exact(Ix, Iy, It, u, v, lamda):
  M = u.shape[0]
  N = u.shape[1]
  nabla = np.zeros((M,N))
  nabla = spnabla(M,N)
  transpose = np.transpose(nabla)
  u_0 = u
  v_0 = v
  Ix = Ix.flatten()
  Iy = Iy.flatten()
  diag_Ix_squared = np.diag(Ix*Ix)
  diag_Ix_Iy = np.diag(Ix*Iy)
  diag_Iy_squared = np.diag(Iy*Iy)
  tmp = lamda*diag_Ix_squared
  A11 = transpose*nabla + tmp 
  A12 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
  A21 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
  A22 = transpose*nabla + lamda*diag_Iy_squared
```

The error ocurrs when I try to create diag_Ix_squared. I am new to python and I do not know how to handle big arrays.

Comment: What does `Ix.shape` give you?

Comment: Shape of Ix is (388L, 584L). Iy, It, u and v have the exact same shape

Comment: Maybe I should not flatten Ix. But if I do not flatten it, I can not compute A11.

Comment: Then only flatten it after the calculation of `A11`.

Comment: If I do not flatten it I do not get the right shapes to compute A11. transpose*nabla has the shape (226592,226592) and tmp has (388L). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know what the problem was. I used dense matrices instead of sparse matrices.

```
 Ix_flat = Ix.flatten()
 Iy_flat = Iy.flatten()
 diag_Ix_squared = sp.spdiags(Ix_flat*Ix_flat, 0, M*N, M*N)
```

That solved my problem. Thanks for your help guys.